# Copy Xbox 360 saves to Xbox One without Cloud

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, xbox-network, backwards-compatibility

I want to copy my old (Fallout 3) saves from my Xbox 360 to the Xbox One to continue playing, maybe even with another Xbox account, and without the Cloud storage.

Is it somehow possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system only supports copying saves from the Xbox 360 to the Xbox One via the cloud.  The steps are shown on the official [Xbox One Backwards Compatibility](http://support.xbox.com/en-us/xbox-one/system/compatibility-with-xbox-360-faq#84c8af3cf32647bebabfbc81f3602105) website under the following question:

> How do I pick up at the same place in a game on Xbox One where I left off on Xbox 360?

Note that without third party modification of your save files, they must be from the same Xbox profile.

If you want to switch the profile a game save is associated with then you will need to look into such tools.  Horizon and Modio are some of the more popular choices.  The official sites for these tools provide tutorials for such functionality.